# Adding a Connectionstring to a custom ASP.net control

Tags: asp.net, custom-controls, sitefinity

I am developing a SiteFinity DLL custom control (custom ASP.net control) that has to connect to an external database (external to SiteFinity's DB) to fetch some data and display it. Problem is that since it is a DLL and not a website, I can't add a connectionstring because there is no web.config file. Is there any way to programatically define the connectionstring or would it work if I create a web.config file in the project and just mark it as an embedded resource?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am sure you can use App.Config file with certain condition. Please go through with below link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/6bd72b9f-5db5-4be2-833f-215a4bd55b3e

Answer (score 1):

If the idea is to use the dll in a website (which it sound like), then you can still use the web.config to store configuration settings and read them at runtime.